# How to override the cipherlist sent to the server by Android when using HttpsURLConnection?

Tags: java, android, ssl, jsse, httpsurlconnection

During TLS negotiation, clients send a list of supported ciphers to the server, the server picks one, and encryption starts. I want to change this cipherlist sent to the server by Android, when I'm using `HttpsURLConnection` for communication.

I know that I can use `setSSLSocketFactory` on the `HttpsURLConnection` object to set it up to use a `SSLSocketFactory`. This is useful when I want to change the trustmanager etc used by the `SSLSocket` returned by the `SSLSocketFactory`.

I know that in general this ciphersuite list can be edited using an `SSLParameters` object and passing it to `SSlsocket` or `SSLEngine` objects using the methods they provide.

BUT the `SSLSocketFactory` does not seem to expose such methods!

I cannot find a way to change the `SSLParameters` of the returned `SSLSocket` objects created by the `SSLSocketFactory` I pass to `HttpsURLConnection`.

What to do?

I guess this is also relevant to Java in general, not only Android. Maybe there's an OO way to do it (e.g. extend `SSLSocketFactory` and provide that to `HttpsURLConnection`?)

Answer (score 19):

This piece of code is a bit raw. please use with care.

```
public class PreferredCipherSuiteSSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {


private static final String PREFERRED_CIPHER_SUITE = "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA";

private final SSLSocketFactory delegate;

public PreferredCipherSuiteSSLSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory delegate) {

    this.delegate = delegate;
}

@Override
public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {

    return setupPreferredDefaultCipherSuites(this.delegate);
}

@Override
public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {

    return setupPreferredSupportedCipherSuites(this.delegate);
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(String arg0, int arg1) throws IOException,
        UnknownHostException {

    Socket socket = this.delegate.createSocket(arg0, arg1);
    String[] cipherSuites = setupPreferredDefaultCipherSuites(delegate);
    ((SSLSocket)socket).setEnabledCipherSuites(cipherSuites);

    return socket;
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(InetAddress arg0, int arg1) throws IOException {

    Socket socket = this.delegate.createSocket(arg0, arg1);
    String[] cipherSuites = setupPreferredDefaultCipherSuites(delegate);
    ((SSLSocket)socket).setEnabledCipherSuites(cipherSuites);

    return socket;
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(Socket arg0, String arg1, int arg2, boolean arg3)
        throws IOException {

    Socket socket = this.delegate.createSocket(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3);
    String[] cipherSuites = setupPreferredDefaultCipherSuites(delegate);
    ((SSLSocket)socket).setEnabledCipherSuites(cipherSuites);

    return socket;
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(String arg0, int arg1, InetAddress arg2, int arg3)
        throws IOException, UnknownHostException {

    Socket socket = this.delegate.createSocket(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3);
    String[] cipherSuites = setupPreferredDefaultCipherSuites(delegate);
    ((SSLSocket)socket).setEnabledCipherSuites(cipherSuites);

    return socket;
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(InetAddress arg0, int arg1, InetAddress arg2,
        int arg3) throws IOException {

    Socket socket = this.delegate.createSocket(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3);
    String[] cipherSuites = setupPreferredDefaultCipherSuites(delegate);
    ((SSLSocket)socket).setEnabledCipherSuites(cipherSuites);

    return socket;
}

private static String[] setupPreferredDefaultCipherSuites(SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory) {

    String[] defaultCipherSuites = sslSocketFactory.getDefaultCipherSuites();

    ArrayList<String> suitesList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(defaultCipherSuites));
    suitesList.remove(PREFERRED_CIPHER_SUITE);
    suitesList.add(0, PREFERRED_CIPHER_SUITE);

    return suitesList.toArray(new String[suitesList.size()]);
}

private static String[] setupPreferredSupportedCipherSuites(SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory) {

    String[] supportedCipherSuites = sslSocketFactory.getSupportedCipherSuites();

    ArrayList<String> suitesList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(supportedCipherSuites));
    suitesList.remove(PREFERRED_CIPHER_SUITE);
    suitesList.add(0, PREFERRED_CIPHER_SUITE);

    return suitesList.toArray(new String[suitesList.size()]);
}
}
```

When you want to use it.

```
            HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) (new URL(url))
                .openConnection();
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        TrustManager tm[] = {new SSLPinningTrustManager()};
        context.init(null, tm, null);
        SSLSocketFactory preferredCipherSuiteSSLSocketFactory = new PreferredCipherSuiteSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
        connection.setSSLSocketFactory(preferredCipherSuiteSSLSocketFactory);
                    connection.connect();
```

Thanks you.

Comment: small precision: this is javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory and not apatche SSLSocketFactory.

Comment: What is SSLPinningTrustManager here? is "SSLPinningTrustManager"  is user defined class as Android Studio is not able to resolve, if yes, then what could be replacement?

Comment: @Amritesh maybe `SSLPinningTrustManager` refers to [this implementation](https://github.com/duladissa/SSLPinnigExample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/litedreamz/sslpinnigexample/util/SSLPinningTrustManager.java)

Answer (score 5):

I bundled the technique in @ThinkChris's answer[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16714084/306864) into a dead simple method call. You can use the [NetCipher](https://guardianproject.info/code/netcipher) library to get a modern TLS config when using Android's `HttpsURLConnection`.  NetCipher configures the `HttpsURLConnection` instance to use the best supported TLS version, removes SSLv3 support, and configures the best suite of ciphers for that TLS version.  First, add it to your *build.gradle*:

```
compile 'info.guardianproject.netcipher:netcipher:1.2'
```

Or you can download the *netcipher-1.2.jar* and include it directly in your app.  Then instead of calling:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) sourceUrl.openConnection();
```

Call this:

```
HttpsURLConnection connection = NetCipher.getHttpsURLConnection(sourceUrl);
```

If you want to specifically customize that cipher list, you can check the code there.  But most people should not have to think about the cipher list, instead it should use the common best practices by default.

Answer (score -1):

This code worked wonders for an unexpected `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException`.

Upgrading to `jdk1.8.0_92` and Oracle JCE unlimited strength policy files did not help, and I was unsuccessful trying to apply specific `SSLParameters` to the `HttpsUrlConnection`.

In particular, attempting to use `HttpsUrlConnection` to read `https://www.adrbnymellon.com` results in the following error:

`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure`

This website worked OK prior to about 4/15/2016, and then started failing. I believe the failure is caused by the website discontinuing support for `SSLv2Hello` and `SSLv3` due to the DROWN vulnerability. See [this](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.adrbnymellon.com&s=52.84.213.194) for a great analysis.

Access to the website started working by modifying the code with changes to just 2 constants:

```
private static final String PREFERRED_CIPHER_SUITE = "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256";
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
```

I hope this helps someone else.