# SSLHandshakeException on Android app when authenticate user using Cloud Endpoints

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio, ssl-certificate, google-cloud-endpoints

I develop a backend using App Engine with Google Endpoints in Android Studio.
Now, from an Android app (still developed with Android Studio) I want to call an API protected by authentication.

Here is the endpoint

```
@ApiMethod(
        name = "signInWithGoogle",
        path = "signInWithGoogle",
        httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.POST
)
public Profile signInWithGoogle(final User user) throws UnauthorizedException {
    if (user == null) {
        throw new UnauthorizedException("Authorization required");
    }
    Key<Profile> profileKey = Key.create(Profile.class, user.getEmail());
    Profile profile = OfyService.ofy().load().key(profileKey).now();
    return profile;
}
```

And here is how I call the API in a separated thread:

```
    GoogleAccountCredential credential = new GoogleAccountCredential(context, Constants.AUDIENCE);
    credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
    SignUser signUser = new SignUser.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(Constants.APP_ENGINE_PROJECT_ID).build();
    Profile profile = signUser.signInWithGoogle().execute();
```

The Audience is `"server:client_id:XXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com"`, where XXXXX is part of the web client id declared in the developer console.

If I call an API not protected by OAuth2 everything works fine. I think the problem is that I miss something trying to authenticate the user.

If you need other info just ask me.
I am really stuck at this point, please help.

**UPDATE**

I forgot the error I get.
When it try to execute the request I get an SSLHandshakeException:

```
12-20 19:24:48.472  19810-19991/com.iseeyou.app W/System.err﹕ javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
12-20 19:24:48.584  19810-19991/com.iseeyou.app W/System.err﹕ at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:374)
12-20 19:24:48.615  19810-19991/com.iseeyou.app W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:197)
12-20 19:24:48.635  19810-19991/com.iseeyou.app W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:151)
12-20 19:24:48.653  19810-19991/com.iseeyou.app W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:276)
12-20 19:24:48.673  19810-19991/com.iseeyou.app W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
12-20 19:24:48.695  19810-19991/com.iseeyou.app W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:373)
12-20 19:24:48.716  19810-19991/com.iseeyou.app W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
12-20 19:24:48.740  19810-19991/com.iseeyou.app W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:208)
12-20 19:24:48.763  19810-19991/com.iseeyou.app W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
12-20 19:24:48.786  19810-19991/com.iseeyou.app W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
12-20 19:24:48.806  19810-19991/com.iseeyou.app W/System.err﹕ at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:77)
12-20 19:24:48.825  19810-19991/com.iseeyou.app W/System.err﹕ at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:965)
12-20 19:24:48.853  19810-19991/com.iseeyou.app W/System.err﹕ at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
12-20 19:24:48.880  19810-19991/com.iseeyou.app W/System.err﹕ at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
12-20 19:24:48.905  19810-19991/com.iseeyou.app W/System.err﹕ at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
12-20 19:24:48.927  19810-19991/com.iseeyou.app W/System.err﹕ at com.iseeyou.app.net.api.signUser.SignInWithGoogleJob.onRun(SignInWithGoogleJob.java:29)
12-20 19:24:48.945  19810-19991/com.iseeyou.app W/System.err﹕ at com.path.android.jobqueue.BaseJob.safeRun(BaseJob.java:108)
12-20 19:24:48.963  19810-19991/com.iseeyou.app W/System.err﹕ at com.path.android.jobqueue.JobHolder.safeRun(JobHolder.java:60)
12-20 19:24:48.985  19810-19991/com.iseeyou.app W/System.err﹕ at com.path.android.jobqueue.executor.JobConsumerExecutor$JobConsumer.run(JobConsumerExecutor.java:201)
12-20 19:24:49.001  19810-19991/com.iseeyou.app W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
12-20 19:24:49.019  19810-19991/com.iseeyou.app W/System.err﹕ Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xaf848200: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
12-20 19:24:49.039  19810-19991/com.iseeyou.app W/System.err﹕ error:1407743E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert inappropriate fallback (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:765 0xac46ce61:0x00000000)
12-20 19:24:49.173  19810-19991/com.iseeyou.app W/System.err﹕ at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
12-20 19:24:49.194  19810-19991/com.iseeyou.app W/System.err﹕ at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:302)
12-20 19:24:49.202  19810-19991/com.iseeyou.app W/System.err﹕ ... 19 more
```

Comment: And what's the problem? Is `User` null value? You can also set the application name with `setApplicationName` before calling `build`. But I'm not sure this may be the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put the log. See the updated question. Btw the application name should not be a problem, given that without authentication I can get the responses from App Engine.

Comment: @DanieleVitali Did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately no :( Do you have any tips?

Comment: This sounds like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27112082. My guess is that it's not strictly endpoints related as it shouldn't break the SSL handshake. It's possible you are only seeing this when trying to access an OAuth protected endpoint as that is when SSL is required.

Comment: @DanieleVitali don't you found a solution yet? i have the same problem **:/**

Comment: well... i solved my problem here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29114785/sslhandshakeexception-when-trying-to-reach-app-engine-endpoint).