# SSLHandshakeException when trying to reach app engine endpoint

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, cloud, endpoints

I'm trying to connect to one of my endpoint methods from an android client to my locally running app engine backend. The problem is I'm getting a SSLHandshakeException. My API is not protected by OAuth. The method I am trying to reach looks like this:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "register")
public UserInfo registerUser(UserInfo userInfo) {
    try {
        checkUserParameters(userInfo);
        ofy().save().entity(userInfo).now();
        return ofy().load().entity(userInfo).now();
    } catch (InvalidPropertiesFormatException e) {
        logger.info(e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

And from my client I am doing this:

```
  if (regService == null) {
            UserInfoApi.Builder builder = new UserInfoApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                   new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
                .setRootUrl(LoginActivity.LOCALHOST_IP)
                .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new GoogleClientRequestInitializer() {
                    @Override
                    public void initialize(AbstractGoogleClientRequest<?> abstractGoogleClientRequest)
                            throws IOException {
                        abstractGoogleClientRequest.setDisableGZipContent(true);
                    }
           });

           regService = builder.build();
           UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo();
           userInfo.setGcmId(registerToGcm());
           userInfo.setAccountName(params[0]);
           userInfo.setEmail(params[0]);
           userInfo.setProfilePictureUrl(null);
           UserInfo userInfo = regService.register(userInfo).execute();
  }
```

For some reason this does not work, I have also tried with the API that you get when importing the backend module to android studio but it gives the same error.

Logs:

```
03-18 12:21:21.642  30454-30477/huka.com.repli W/System.err﹕ javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
03-18 12:21:21.642  30454-30477/huka.com.repli W/System.err﹕ at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:374)
03-18 12:21:21.642  30454-30477/huka.com.repli W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:197)
03-18 12:21:21.643  30454-30477/huka.com.repli W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:151)
03-18 12:21:21.643  30454-30477/huka.com.repli W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:276)
03-18 12:21:21.643  30454-30477/huka.com.repli W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
03-18 12:21:21.643  30454-30477/huka.com.repli W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:373)
03-18 12:21:21.643  30454-30477/huka.com.repli W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
03-18 12:21:21.643  30454-30477/huka.com.repli W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:208)
03-18 12:21:21.643  30454-30477/huka.com.repli W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
03-18 12:21:21.643  30454-30477/huka.com.repli W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
03-18 12:21:21.643  30454-30477/huka.com.repli W/System.err﹕ at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:77)
03-18 12:21:21.643  30454-30477/huka.com.repli W/System.err﹕ at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:965)
03-18 12:21:21.643  30454-30477/huka.com.repli W/System.err﹕ at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
03-18 12:21:21.643  30454-30477/huka.com.repli W/System.err﹕ at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
03-18 12:21:21.643  30454-30477/huka.com.repli W/System.err﹕ at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
03-18 12:21:21.643  30454-30477/huka.com.repli W/System.err﹕ at gcm.GcmRegistrationAsyncTask.registerToService(GcmRegistrationAsyncTask.java:80)
03-18 12:21:21.643  30454-30477/huka.com.repli W/System.err﹕ at gcm.GcmRegistrationAsyncTask.doInBackground(GcmRegistrationAsyncTask.java:69)
03-18 12:21:21.643  30454-30477/huka.com.repli W/System.err﹕ at gcm.GcmRegistrationAsyncTask.doInBackground(GcmRegistrationAsyncTask.java:26)
03-18 12:21:21.643  30454-30477/huka.com.repli W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
03-18 12:21:21.643  30454-30477/huka.com.repli W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
03-18 12:21:21.643  30454-30477/huka.com.repli W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
03-18 12:21:21.643  30454-30477/huka.com.repli W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
03-18 12:21:21.643  30454-30477/huka.com.repli W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
03-18 12:21:21.643  30454-30477/huka.com.repli W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
03-18 12:21:21.643  30454-30477/huka.com.repli W/System.err﹕ Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xaf724200: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
03-18 12:21:21.643  30454-30477/huka.com.repli W/System.err﹕ error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:790 0xac490e61:0x00000000)
03-18 12:21:21.644  30454-30477/huka.com.repli W/System.err﹕ at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
03-18 12:21:21.644  30454-30477/huka.com.repli W/System.err﹕ at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:302)
03-18 12:21:21.644  30454-30477/huka.com.repli W/System.err﹕ ... 23 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So... The problem was I was using https instead of http when setting rootUrl on the client.

Comment: i did the same thing kkkkkkkk

Comment: I haven't set rooturl. Now one of the 30 clients it gives this error... The generated client has an https url as default parameter in the builder constructor. Why does it work on 29 of the 30 clients and on 1 it gives this error?!

Comment: How did you change from https to http? see my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33068783/using-http-instead-of-https-in-appengine-endpoint-to-avoid-sslhandshakeexception

Comment: Changing the https to http throws this exception: `com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code": 403,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "message": "SSL is required to perform this operation.",
      "reason": "sslRequired"
    }
  ],
  "message": "SSL is required to perform this operation."
}`