# Using http instead of https in AppEngine endpoint to avoid SSLHandshakeException

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, sslhandshakeexception

My problem is the same as [SSLHandshakeException when trying to reach app engine endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29114785/sslhandshakeexception-when-trying-to-reach-app-engine-endpoint) (so yes, it's a duplicate to that extent). The answer there says that I need to change from https to http. So how do I do that? I am using java app engine.

My `web.xml` does **not** have anywhere

```
<user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
```

Also in the android client, I connect to the server with

```
MyServer service = MyServer.Builder builder = new MyServer.Builder(
        AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
        new AndroidJsonFactory(),
        null
    );
```

**to be clear**

I can confirm that my code is indeed using https, I look into the generated source and found:

```
public Builder(HttpTransport transport, JsonFactory jsonFactory, HttpRequestInitializer httpRequestInitializer) { 
  super(transport, jsonFactory,
  "https://mycompanyserver.appspot.com/_ah/api/", "server/1/",
  httpRequestInitializer, false); 
}
```

I just don't know how to prevent it from asking for https.

**I am able to reach the site from the browser, and so the problem may be android studio server certificate**

Do I need to add appengine server certificate to android studio? When I go to `android studio > Preferences >Server Certificates`, under `Accepted Certificates` I see `N/A > untangle`. How would I go about adding my app engine certificate to android studio?

And since I added my [Appengine module using the android studio instructions](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/HelloEndpoints), why was it not auto-included?

Comment: Facing the same problem.