# Handshake fail on Lollipop

Tags: java, android, ssl, apache-httpclient-4.x, sslhandshakeexception

I'm trying to do a HTTP POST but I get two different errors:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
```

I fixed the **No peer certificate** error through a workaround as specified here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4837230/4254419

but while that fixes the error, it throws a new error instead, which is **Handshake failed**

I know it's not safe and I don't care, it's not for production so I care less about security. Is there a fix for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
I found a link https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=88313 where I found a code:

```
public class MySSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

        ...

        @Override
        public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
            final SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
            sslSocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(sslSocket.getSupportedCipherSuites());
            return sslSocket;
        }

        @Override
        public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
            final SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
            sslSocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(sslSocket.getSupportedCipherSuites());
            return sslSocket;
        }
}
```

You can use code of `MySSLSocketFactory` from the link you've provided but you need to override two methods `createSocket` as I've wrote above.
Also it's not the best solution you can have some security issue later, because for connection it can use some old cipher algorithm.

Hope this helps.