# Get SSL Version used in HttpsURLConnection - Java

Tags: java, ssl, httpsurlconnection

I am developing a java agent to monitor http communications happening in my application server. I like to know the SSL version(SSLv3, TLS, etc) used in outgoing Https connections. Is there a way to get the SSL version by any means?

Answer (score 11):

I used this solution, maybe it can help you:

First you need an extension class of `SSLSocketFactory` to attach a `HandshakeCompletedListener` to the sockets created by the `SSLSocketFactory`:
(inspired by [How to override the cipherlist sent to the server by Android when using HttpsURLConnection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16299531/how-to-override-the-cipherlist-sent-to-the-server-by-android-when-using-httpsurl))

```
public class SecureSSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
private final SSLSocketFactory delegate;
private HandshakeCompletedListener handshakeListener;

public SecureSSLSocketFactory(
        SSLSocketFactory delegate, HandshakeCompletedListener handshakeListener) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
    this.handshakeListener = handshakeListener;
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(Socket s, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) 
    throws IOException {
    SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) this.delegate.createSocket(s, host, port, autoClose);

    if (null != this.handshakeListener) {
        socket.addHandshakeCompletedListener(this.handshakeListener);
    }

    return socket;
}
// and so on for all the other createSocket methods of SSLSocketFactory.

@Override
public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
    // TODO: or your own preferences
    return this.delegate.getDefaultCipherSuites();
}

@Override
public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
    // TODO: or your own preferences
    return this.delegate.getSupportedCipherSuites();
}
```

Then you need an implementation of the `HandshakeCompletedListener` interface. You must implement the `handshakeCompleted` method:

```
public class MyHandshakeCompletedListener implements HandshakeCompletedListener {
@Override
public void handshakeCompleted(HandshakeCompletedEvent event) {
    SSLSession session = event.getSession();
    String protocol = session.getProtocol();
    String cipherSuite = session.getCipherSuite();
    String peerName = null;

    try {
        peerName = session.getPeerPrincipal().getName();
    } catch (SSLPeerUnverifiedException e) {
    }
}
```

In `handshakeCompleted` you can get the protocol version (maybe TLSv1.2), and by the way also the information on cipher suite etc., that is also accessible via `HttpsConnection`.
You can set the custom SSL socket factory via `conn.setSSLSocketFactory` before connect:

```
private void setupAndConnect() {
URL url = new URL("https://host.dom/xyz");
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(/*keyManagers*/null, /*trustManagers*/null, /*new SecureRandom()*/null);    // simple here

conn.setSSLSocketFactory(new SecureSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory(), new MyHandshakeCompletedListener()));

// conn.set... /* set other parameters */
conn.connect();
```